# Multiple Partitions Lubuntu Install

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, system-installation

I want to install `Lubuntu` on my laptop which has a 20GB SSD and a 300GB hard disk. Is there a way to install just `/boot` onto the SSD and all the other files, like `/home` onto the hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I believe so when you get to the "Installation Type" select "Something Else".

When creating partitions declare the desired mount point. ie "/boot" and "/", etc

This seems to be a simple guide to the tool and how to get to it.
http://easyaosp.blogopogo.com/2013/04/28/obtain-and-compile-aosp-using-lubuntu-second-step-install-lubuntu/

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Just a /boot which is usually 300 to 500MB on SSD will not add much speed.
But with 20GB, you can install entire / (root) into SSD so system is running from SSD. Then /home on rotating hard drive.

I have a separate SSD and only use 11GB including /home (about 2GB with wine for Picasa) used. But I am aggressive about moving data to data partitions on rotating drive including some hidden data like the Firefox & Thunderbird profiles.